# Real time Sync between two folders on different servers

Tags: ubuntu, network-share, directory, synchronization

What is the best way to sync two folders completely in real time over two servers (Ubuntu) in same network?  Do you think syncing folders is a better idea than having a shared folder? If a shared folder is better, how can I set this up?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Without some context, there's no way to answer this.

Comment: What do you mean by "real-time"?  With any synchronization, there's going to be some latency; whether it's noticed or not is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally lean towards a shared folder for this sort of thing.  But it does depend on exactly how you're using it.  (I'd recommend following Mark's advice for more context)

For Linux, the easiest thing thing would be using NFS mounts.  You can do it one of two ways.  Either 1) export the folder from one of your two servers, and have the the other mount it, or 2) have a separate server (ie: A centralized file server) export a folder, and have both servers mount it.  Generic documentation on how to use NFS can be f[ound all over the place.](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/)  But sound off if you need specifics.

Comment: NFS over DRBD may be what he wants if he needs HA.

Answer (score 0):

I use gbridge because I'm usually using Windows, that seems to work pretty well, but since you want to something for ubuntu, you could check out unison, although I haven't tried it myself, it seems like it might work for you

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/unison-file-synchronization-tool.html

Comment: Does Unison do real time sync?

Answer (score 0):

I think NFS is the way to go. Sharing instead of synchronization saves on network traffic as well, but it depends upon your ultimate goal. If backup or DR is your goal, perhaps a fileshare is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous: Software using File Systems:

- Using [GFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFS2) File System
- Using [HDFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#HDFS) File System
- NetApp [StorageGRID WebScale](http://www.netapp.com/us/products/object-storage/storagegrid/storagegrid-software.aspx) with File Gateway - proprietary Software

Synchronous: using proprietary Hardware:

- NetApp [MetroCluster](http://www.netapp.com/us/products/protection-software/metrocluster.aspx) (Hihg-Avalability). Second site not available for R/W until disaster takeover/switchover. Data 100% in Sync.
- NetApp [SnapMirror](http://www.netapp.com/us/products/protection-software/snapmirror.aspx) Sync (an the moment 7-Mode only). Second site available for RO with 3 min delay (but data 100% in Sync), manual takeover.

Async Software:

- [BitSync](https://www.getsync.com/) Proprietary
- [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) Open-source
- [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/) Open-source